# How do I display thumbnail of pdf and doc file which I have uploaded in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a situation where I am uploading every type of file to a database and displaying related icons in the view, but I want to display a thumbnail for each file like I am displaying the image for an image file.

How can I show a thumbnail for the doc, pdf, xlxs, or any file format?

Here is my code to upload files:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadResources(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && 
        Request.Form["SelectedSubCategoryId"] != null && 
        Request.Form["SelectedCategoryId"] != null)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (files != null && files.Length > 0 && files[0] != null )
        {
            string[] results = new string[files.Length];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                string ext = string.Empty;
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                int fileExtPos = fileName.LastIndexOf(".");
                if (fileExtPos >= 0)
                    ext = fileName.Substring(fileExtPos, (fileName.Length - fileExtPos));

                results[i] = dat.UploadResources(
                    Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SelectedCategoryId"]), 
                    Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SelectedSubCategoryId"]), 
                    Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Description"]), 
                    WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, 
                    Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form["IsDisplay"]),
                    Convert.ToString(Request.Form["YoutubeURL"]), 
                    file.FileName, 
                    ext, 
                    file.InputStream);

                i++;
            }

            if (results.Any(m => m == "1"))
            {
                string Upfilenames = string.Empty;
                string Npfilenames = string.Empty;
                int m = 0;
                foreach (string s in results)
                {
                    if (s == "1")
                    {
                        Upfilenames += files[m].FileName + ",";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Npfilenames += files[m].FileName + ",";
                    }
                    m++;
                }
               TempData["Message"] = "Success:" + Upfilenames + "were uploaded.";
            }
            if (results.Any(m => m == "-2"))
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Danger: File not uploaded, Please try again.";
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    TempData["Message"] = "Success: All files were uploaded.";
            //}
        }
        else if (Request.Form["YoutubeURL"] != null)
        {
            result = dat.UploadResources(
                Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SelectedCategoryId"]), 
                Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SelectedSubCategoryId"]), 
                Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Description"]), 
                WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, 
                Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form["IsDisplay"]), 
                Convert.ToString(Request.Form["YoutubeURL"]), 
                null, null, null);

            if (result == "1")
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Success: Resource uploaded.";
            }
            else if (result == "-2")
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Danger: Resource not uploaded, Please try again.";
            }
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("UploadResources");
}
```

and this one too:

```
public string UploadResources(
    int CategoryId, int SubCategoryId, string Description, int AdminId, bool IsDisplay,
    string YoutubeURL = null, string FileName = null, string fileExt = null, Stream Media = null)
{
    string RetValue      = string.Empty;
    string ProcedureName = string.Empty;
    string ReturnValue   = string.Empty;
    string regex = "^(?:https?\\:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be\\/|youtube\\.com\\/(?:embed\\/|v\\/|watch\\?v\\=))([\\w-]{10,12})(?:$|\\&|\\?\\#).*";
    string YoutubeID = string.Empty;

    if (YoutubeURL != null)
    {   
        YoutubeID = new Regex(regex).Match(YoutubeURL).Groups[1].Value;
    }

    ProcedureName = "BP_UPLOAD_RESOURCE";
    using (con = new SqlConnection(constrBrandpier))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ProcedureName, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY_ID"    , CategoryId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUB_CATEGORY_ID", SubCategoryId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME"       , FileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILEEXT"        , fileExt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPTION"    , Description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADMINID"        , AdminId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YOUTUBE_URL"    , YoutubeURL);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YOUTUBE_ID"     , YoutubeID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ISDISPLAY", SqlDbType.Char)).Value = IsDisplay ? '1' : '0';

            SqlParameter IMAGEID = new SqlParameter();
            IMAGEID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMAGEID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300);
            IMAGEID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter intReturn = new SqlParameter();
            intReturn = cmd.Parameters.Add("@INTRETURN", SqlDbType.Int);
            intReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            RetValue = intReturn.Value.ToString();

            if (intReturn.Value.ToString() == "1" && FileName != null)
            {
                string _bucketpath = 
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bucketName"].ToString() + 
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourcebucketName"].ToString() + 
                    CategoryId.ToString() + "/" + SubCategoryId.ToString();
                BWS.AWS.S3 s3 = new BWS.AWS.S3();
                string _returns3 = s3.UploadFile(_bucketpath, IMAGEID.Value.ToString(), ReadFully(Media));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RetValue = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }

    return RetValue;
}
```

Comment: I displaying icon but i want to display thumbnail image because that's more appropriate than icons.

Answer (score 0):

For the image that was uploaded you could use Twitter's bootstrap thumbnail class like below.

```
<img src="<path-to-uploaded image>" class="img-thumbnail" alt="This is a thumbnail image" width="150" height="100">
```

You can see more at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp

As for PDF icons, I'd just use a standard image with the PDF logo and use that.

My two cents.